# Breaking ocean waves on other planets possible?

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics

I have always wondered if there were an ocean on another planet with stronger or weaker gravity, would it be possible to have breaking waves?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.The breaking dynamics would occur at different rates depending on the magnitude of density difference and gravity.For example the speed of the wave breaking motion is slower for smaller density differences as compared to large density differences where the breaking motion is faster.Look up internal waves, they are waves that occur in the interior of the ocean where the density differences are different than on the surface and you still see breaking events.Although these waves move relatively slower and are much larger in amplitude the motion is still qualitatively the same.

Answer (score 4):

Breaking waves are understood as a breakdown in the solutions of the shallow wave equations. So yes there will be breaking waves on any world that has liquid seas with wind to generate waves big enough and shores where the sea becomes shallow. Stronger gravity would modify the speed and height of the waves but if the wind is strong enough and the oceans big enough for the wind to stir the waves up, then there should still be breaking waves.

Comment: Waves caused by tidal force (or even undersea earthquakes) are subject to the same shallow depth limit equations.

Answer (score 3):

Any planet that has liquid on its surface pretty much has to have *some* atmosphere, else the liquid would have evaporated and the gas diffused into space long ago.  It is hard to imagine a planet with a reasonable atmosphere not having wind.  Since all it takes is wind over liquid to make waves, which will be breaking if there is a sloping shore (also hard to imagine wouldn't be the case somewhere), I don't think you'd find a planet with at least pond-size liquid on its surface not having breaking waves.  The size and speed of propagation will differ with gravity, viscosity, and density of the liquid.

Note that here on Earth even small ponds with light wind have breaking waves.  They may only be a few mm high in that case, but if there are waves and some minimum slope to the shorline, there will be breaking waves.

Comment: No shores on a water world, though ;).

Comment: The partial pressure of many liquids is dang low:  Hg is  0.2729 mmHg,  compared with roughly 10mmHg for H2O, for example.  A less likely fluid to appear "in nature" on this planet might be Silicone fluid DC 705, with a vapor pressure of 2.6 × 10−8.  That'd never evaporate, atmosphere or not -- and anyway, evaporation of a fluid depends on its abundance in the atmosphere, not on the existence of any other molecule in the atmosphere.   Signed, Mr. Ultra-nitpicker

Comment: @Carl: Yes, there are liquids with such low vapor pressure to not force the existance of a substantial enough atmosphere to make enough wind to make waves.  However, very very likely there are other planets where water, methane, and other reasonably volatile liquids exist on the surface.  Good point about atmosphere not blocking evaporation into space.  That's all about gravity, the resulting escape velocity, and the velocity distribution (temperature) of the molecules in question in the upper atmosphere.